# Wrapping images in WordPress with DOMDocument

Tags: php, wordpress, domdocument

I’m trying to add a div wrapper around each image in my WordPress blog and trying to achieve this using DOMDocment in my functions.php.
Unfortunately, only the closing tag of my wrapper is applied to the ouput. The opening tag is missing for all images.

My function looks like this:

```
function lazyload($content){
$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML(utf8_decode($content), LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
libxml_clear_errors();


$div = $dom->createElement('div');
$images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');

foreach ($images as $image) {
    $div_clone = $div->cloneNode();
    $image->parentNode->replaceChild($div_clone, $image);
    $div_clone->appendChild($image);
}

$html = $dom->saveHTML();
return $html; 
}
```

This occurs only when wrapping img. I tried to wrap each paragraph tag instead and all of them got opening and closing wrapper tags.

Has anybody an idea how to fix this?
Instead of `return $html` I tried also `echo $html`. In ths case both tags were applied, but the captions were echoed as short tags instead of the parsed html elements.

Answer (score 1):

Hello_ friend.

I achieved what you are trying to do with a helper `DOMDocument` object like this:

```
function lazyload($content) {
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $dom->loadHTML(utf8_decode($content), LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
    libxml_clear_errors();

    // This object will hold the updated content
    $newContent = new DOMDocument();

    $images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');

    foreach ($images as $image) {

        $div = $newContent->createElement('div');
        $div->appendChild($newContent->importNode($image));
        $newContent->appendChild($div);

    }

    $html = $newContent->saveHTML();
    return $html;
} 

// Test
$html = '<img alt="image 1"><img alt="image 2"><img alt="image 3"><img alt="image 4"><img alt="image 5"><img alt="image 6"><img alt="image 7"><img alt="image 8">';
echo lazyload($html);

// OUTPUT
<div>
    <img alt="image 1">
</div>
<div>
    <img alt="image 2">
</div>
<div>
    <img alt="image 3">
</div>
<div>
    <img alt="image 4">
</div>
<div>
    <img alt="image 5">
</div>
<div>
    <img alt="image 6">
</div>
<div>
    <img alt="image 7">
</div>
<div>
    <img alt="image 8">
</div>
```

**NOTE:** In your code I see you are using [DOMDocument::createElement](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createelement.php), but I never see you to append this newly created `<div>` to the **DOM** and documentation says:

> public DOMElement DOMDocument::createElement ( string $name [, string
>   $value ] )
>
> This function creates a new instance of class DOMElement. **This node
>   will not show up in the document unless it is inserted with (e.g.)
>   DOMNode::appendChild().**

Let me know if the function that I edited is working for you.

Good Luck!

**EDIT**

your statement was a good point. If you want to use it on whole your **DOM** content you should take another approach:

```
function lazyload($content) {
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $dom->loadHTML(utf8_decode($content), LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
    libxml_clear_errors();

    $images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');

    foreach ($images as $image) {

        $div = $dom->createElement('div');
        $div->appendChild($image->cloneNode());

        // optional
        $div->setAttribute('class', 'your-lazy-loading-img-class');

        // replace img with the wrapper that is holding the <img>
        $image->parentNode->replaceChild($div, $image);
    }

    return $dom->saveHTML();
}


// Test
$html = '
    <h1 class="h1">Heading 1</h1>
    <div class="multiple-images-wrapper">
        <div class="inner-wrapper"><img alt="image 1"></div>
        <img alt="image 2">
        <img alt="image 3">
    </div>

    <h2>Heading 2</h2>
    <img alt="image 4">
    <img alt="image 5">';

// htmlspecialchars is only for testing purpose 
echo htmlspecialchars(lazyload($html));
exit;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h1 class="h1">Heading 1</h1> 
        <div class="multiple-images-wrapper"> 
            <div class="inner-wrapper">
                <div class="your-lazy-loading-img-class">
                    <img alt="image 1">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="your-lazy-loading-img-class">
                <img alt="image 2">
            </div>
            <div class="your-lazy-loading-img-class">
                <img alt="image 3">
            </div>
        </div>
        <h2>Heading 2</h2> 
        <div class="your-lazy-loading-img-class">
            <img alt="image 4">
        </div>
        <div class="your-lazy-loading-img-class">
            <img alt="image 5">
        </div>
        <div class="your-lazy-loading-img-class">
            <img alt="image 6">
        </div>
        <div class="your-lazy-loading-img-class">
            <img alt="image 7">
        </div>
        <div class="your-lazy-loading-img-class">
            <img alt="image 8">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**NOTE**

**See that I omitted LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED because with this flag seems that DOMDocument is not functioning as expected (for me). If you change to `$dom->loadHTML(utf8_decode($content), LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);` you will see output like this:**

```
<h1 class="h1">Heading 1
    <div class="multiple-images-wrapper"> 
        <div class="inner-wrapper">
            <div class="your-lazy-loading-img-class">
                <img alt="image 1">
            </div>
        </div> 
        <div class="your-lazy-loading-img-class">
            <img alt="image 2">
        </div> 
        <div class="your-lazy-loading-img-class">
            <img alt="image 3">
        </div> 
    </div>
    <h2>Heading 2</h2>
    <div class="your-lazy-loading-img-class">
        <img alt="image 4">
    </div>
    <div class="your-lazy-loading-img-class">
        <img alt="image 5">
    </div>
</h1>
```

So according to me if you want a reliable HTML avoid using **LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED** and then if you don't need `<html><body></body></html>` simply clear those tags from the returned string with some basic technique like string replace or string cut to position.

Comment: Hi @sand, thanks for your answer! This code works for me, but of cause it just returns divs and images. How would I have to alter the code so that all of my content is returned as well? ($content includes paragraphs, iframes, images, lists and so on. I’d like to wrap each image in a div but have returned all other tags unchanged)

Comment: @Tibor your statement was right and I did an update to give you some ideas how can you approach :)